# Mathematica : duplicate edges

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to generate a graph from an adjacency list, but Mathematica doesn't want to plot my graph because of multiple edges i think.
This is my script :

```
Needs["GraphUtilities`"]
data = Import["adj_matrix.txt", "Table"];
data2 = Flatten[Table[{data[[i, 1]] \[UndirectedEdge] data[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, 
  Length[data]}]];
graph1 = Graph[data2]
```

The error i get is :
    Graph::supp: Mixed graphs and multigraphs are not supported.

I do not have any "proper" duplicates in my list, the only type of duplicates that appear are 1->2 and 2->1. 
I would like to know how to delete these "duplicates" from my list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly convert an adjacency matrix to a `Graph` using [`AdjacencyGraph[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AdjacencyGraph.html).  This is probably the simplest solution:

```
AdjacencyGraph[data]
```

If your matrix contains other elements than 0 and 1, use

```
AdjacencyGraph@Clip[data]
```

To filter out duplicates from the edge list of an undirected graph, use

```
Union[Sort /@ edgeList]
```

Comment: What I am using is not an adjacency matrix, but more a list. it looks like this:
1->2
1->4
2->1
2->5 etc...

Comment: @Julia, the `Union[Sort /@ edgeList]` is what you need.